# Is it possible to speed up the F# compiler?

Tags: f#, mono

As of F# 1.9.6.16 and Mono 2.4.2.3 I am failing to AOT the F# assemblies, getting a segmentation fault. `fsi` is barely usable (and sometimes crashes), and `fsc` is quite painfully slow. Under windows, F# is not the fastest compiler either. Is there anything to help the situation?

Comment: Can you try it under .NET with that version of F# and see if it is a F# compiler problem or a mono issue?

Comment: Ah yes, `ngen.exe install "C:\Program Files\FSharp-1.9.6.16\bin\fsc.exe"` gives "All compilation targets are up to date". So one of the reasons that the F# compiler `fsc` is faster on Windows is that its installer has pre-compiled it to native code, which Mono fails to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to help this situation is to file bugs.  If you have a particular project or environment which is having a significant slow down I highly encourage you to file a bug.  Often times real world customer scenarios are very instructive in tracking down performance problems in products.

F#, like the rest of the languages in visual studio, process customer bugs filed via Microsoft's connect website.

- http://connect.microsoft.com

(EDIT: In the specific case of F#, you are also welcome to email fsbugs@microsoft.com.)

Comment: Do you fix bugs that may be an interaction between the F# compiler and mono? <g>

Comment: @James, I don't work on F# so I don't have a point of reference.  Probably the best place to ask this is on fsbugs@microsoft.com

Comment: As far as I know from sending bugs to fsbugs@microsoft.com, they don't support Mono, but are working on a general compiler speedup for the next release. Would be interesting to know if anything can be done right now without waiting for the new F#.

Answer (score 4):

I just found a way to write F# scripts on Linux that do not rely on `fsi` but rather automatically recompile and are therefore reasonably fast:

Given `/usr/local/bin/fsx`:

```
#!/bin/bash
src=$1
tgt=$src.exe
if [[ $src -nt $tgt ]]
then
    fsc $src -o $tgt >/dev/null && exec mono $tgt
else
    exec mono $tgt
fi
```

One can write scripts that omit the shebang, relying on the default shell:

```
#light (*
    exec fsx $0
*)

printfn "Hello, world!"
```

When run, the shell skips the first line thinking it is a comment, and runs `exec fsx $0`, which compiles the script with `fsc` if the executable is out of date, and then runs it. For F#, the shell command is just a comment.

Answer (score 1):

In Mac OS X, the program is `fsharpi`.

hello.fs:

```
#light (*
    exec fsharpi --exec $0 --quiet
*)

System.Console.WriteLine "Hello World"
```